# Moving file from folder to folder

Tags: c#

```
:20:S10734539/940
```

am reading swift messages from a folder, and at line :20: I perform some sort of validation to know if the file and reading is valid. In this case if line :20: has 940 in it, the windows service reads and moves it to a success folder when done. But an invalid file will not have 940 on line :20: , the windows service is meant to move the invalid file to an invalid file location. I have written a code to do that, but it not able to move the file. I get an error message 'file in use' find below snippets of my code.

```
    if (Directory.Exists(@CBN_INFLOW940))
DirectoryInfo dr = new DirectoryInfo(CBN_INFLOW940);
                        FileInfo[] fi = dr.GetFiles();
                        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(CBN_INFLOW940);
```

int lengthchk = 0;

```
if (files.Length < 1)
    check = false;

while (files.Length > lengthchk)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    logger.Info(fi[lengthchk].Name + ": read from folder");
    string narrationgen = "";
    bool isvalidrtgs = false;
    DateTime createddate = fi[lengthchk].CreationTime.Date;
    FileStream stream = null;
    try
    {
    stream = File.Open(files[lengthchk], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    StreamReader sf = new StreamReader(stream);

     }
```

and

```
if (line.Contains(":20:"))
{
        firstchk = 1;
        if (!line.Contains('/'))
        {
            string[] fnamesplit = fi[lengthchk].Name.Split('.');
            string newfname = fnamesplit[0] + "_bk" + ".txt";
            string destlocation = Invalidfilelocation940 + newfname;
            string sourcelocation = CBN_INFLOW940 + fi[lengthchk]; //  + "\\"
            File.Move(sourcelocation, destlocation);
            return;
        }
        string[] narr = line.Split('/');
        string filecode = narr[1];

        if (filecode.Trim() != "940")
        {
            string[] fnamesplit = fi[lengthchk].Name.Split('.');
            string newfname = fnamesplit[0] + "_bk" + ".txt";
            string destlocation = Invalidfilelocation940 + newfname;
            string sourcelocation = CBN_INFLOW940 + "\\" + fi[lengthchk];
            File.Move(sourcelocation, destlocation);

            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: When posting code here, *don't* use tabs and try to limit the indent. This makes code easier to read.

Comment: Also, do you make sure you close the file before attempting to move?

Comment: Try to split out your check code from your move code.  It will be a better design, plus you may be locking the file for reading while you are trying to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split out your check code from your move code.  It will be a better design, plus you may be locking the file for reading while you are trying to move it.

Think:

```
if ( ShouldMoveFile( filename ) )
{
    File.Move...
}
```

And make sure you close the file you are reading.

If you keep the code the same:

add the lines:

```
sf.Close();
stream.Close();
```

before you go to move the files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you have the file open for read write.

```
stream = File.Open(files[lengthchk], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

The file Access here is the killer `FileAccess.ReadWrite`

Possibly if you open it just for read you'll be able to move it, but really, when you're done reading the file you should close it before you try to move it.

Ideally you'd have one method to check does the file need to move, and another to perform the move.

Comment: I changed the file access to read, but its still not moving. After validation, a webservice reads the file and when done, moves to another location, but when validation is false, it not able to move the file.

Comment: then you need to close the file before you try to move it.